# PyObject_AsReadBuffer porting issue

Tags: python, c, porting

As we know  PyObject_AsReadBuffer was changed in version2.5.

On v2.4, we can use it like this,

```
int bufferLength = 0;
const void* buffer = NULL;
PyObject_AsReadBuffer(pyObj, &buffer, &buffer_len);
```

But I have to modify it like this to run on v2.7,

```
Py_ssize_t bufferLength = 0;
const void* buffer = NULL;
PyObject_AsReadBuffer(pyObj, &buffer, &buffer_len);
```

if I want to run it on both v2.4 and v2.7, how should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in include/python2.7/patchlevel.h

```
#define PY_MAJOR_VERSION        2
#define PY_MINOR_VERSION        7
```

So we can use PY_MAJOR_VERSION  PY_MINOR_VERSION to compare the version